# Google Map is not visible when clicked in navigation drawer. There are no errors in displayed in logcat

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

> Google Map is not loading when clicked in navigation drawer. And no
>   errors in logcat.
>
> This is the activity used for displaying maps

HomeActivity.java

```
package com.example.location;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class HomeActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    Marker marker;
    ImageUploadInfo user;
    String url;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home,container,false);
        SupportMapFragment fragment=(SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Incident");
        reference.push().setValue(marker);
        getActivity().setTitle("Home");
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    ImageUploadInfo user=snapshot.getValue(ImageUploadInfo.class);
                    LatLng location= new LatLng(user.imageLatitdue,user.imageLongitude);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(user.timeDate).snippet(user.imageURL)).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));

                    url=user.imageURL;

                  /*  Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("image", url);
                    Intent in=new Intent(MapsActivity.this,DisplayAcc.class);
                    in.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(in);*/
                    //  Intent myIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,DisplayAcc.class);
                    //startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this.getActivity(),DisplayAcc.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", url);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

> This is the xml file:

HomeActivity.xml

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/maps"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

> In navigation drawer activity:
>
> I am using this code to be displayed in window:

```
FragmentManager manager= getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.home:
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new HomeActivity()).commit();
                break;
...............
......
.......
}
```

> There are no errors shown in the logcat, so i'm not able to find out
>   what is the error.
>
> Please kindly help me out. Thank You in advance

[image][LOGCAT1[[image: LOGCAT2[![LOGCAT3[![LOGCAT4[![LOGCAT5]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsdNO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nvqC.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erBe3.png)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO3RD.png)

Comment: did you add meta tag and api key in manifest ?

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

Comment: Yes i have added. As you can see above

Answer (score 2):

The memory of the device may be full or you did not add api key in the manifest file.
you can use link :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Answer (score 0):

Replace your meta with this:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Add this in manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

And also replace your fragment code with this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Make sure you are testing it in real device and play services updated

Comment: I am testing it in real device

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />                This also should be placed in Manifest file right????